# modify namespace in XML using XSL transformation sheet

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, transform

I'm facing an issue while trying to change my XML namespace definition.

I have this namespace in my input XML:
`<ns3:DataElement xmlns:ns3="http://fakeurl_V3/xsd">`

and lower in my XML I have a field:
`<productsList xsi:type="ns3:Segment" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">`

In my XSL I did this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   
    xmlns:ns2="http://fakeurl_V2/xsd"
    xmlns:ns3="http://fakeurl_V3/xsd"
... others namespace ....
>

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="no"
        encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
....

<xsl:template match="ns3:*">
  <xsl:element name="ns2:{local-name()}">
  
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

....
```

there is the result:

```
<ns2:DataElement xmlns:ns2="http://fakeurl_V2/xsd">

<productsList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                    xsi:type="ns3:Segment">
```

As you can see the namespace ns2 has been changed as I wish.

But it did not affect this line: `xsi:type="ns3:Segment"` that I need to transform in: `xsi:type="ns2:Segment"`

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: The thing is that the content of the `xsi:type` attribute is not a namespace, but a meaningless string. You need to modify it using string manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , do you any idea how i can work on a string inside a param ?
I know i will need to use something like : 
select="fn:replace(fn:string(fn:starts-with('xsi:type', 'ns3')), 'ns3', 'ns2')"

Comment: this is probably not the good way ; fn:starts-with('xsi:type', 'ns3') but just an exemple

Answer (score 0):

You could add a template to replace the old prefix with the new one, such as:

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:type">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="replace(., '^ns3:', 'ns2:')" />
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVrvcxa